# Angular 6 routing for all files in particular route

Tags: angular

Is there a way to write an Angular 6 route and component for our videos subfolder that is located inside the assets directory? I need to check to make sure a user is authenticated before the browser search bar just starts playing a video directly from the assets/videos directory?

If someone enters: 'DomainName.com/assets/videos/video123.mp4' the file is just served to anyone. Is this possible to have a route/component that will fire for something like: 'DomainName.com/assets/videos/allfiles'

If it matters our backend is windows server / IIS.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a guard for the /videos and all each children like so

```
  { path: 'videos', component: VideosComponet , canActivate: [CanActivateApp], children: [

      { path: ':video', component: otherVideoComponet }, // for /videos/video123.mp4
    ]
```

Comment: I experimented with the route guard but it seems that if you request a file directly in the browser search bar like 'DomainName.com/videos/video123.mp4' it does not trigger any angular code, like a route or component.  IIS on the server and the browser just get the file directly and it starts playing without the opportunity for a guard or component to intervene? Can you test your idea with an actual mp4 or mp3 file and see if you get a guard to fire? Thank you.